# Disable WIFI on iPhone using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible using Objective-C on an iPhone to disable all WIFI connections.  We have an organization that only wants data to be sent over the cell connection and doesn't want the phone able to join any WIFI networks.  We are looking at writing an app that would either keep WIFI turned off or detect when it connects to a network and then disconnect it.

Comment: I think this would be considered a security flaw if you could do it.

Comment: @danh Well, since the Settings app can do it, there **must** be a way for doing this.

Comment: You mean there must be software access to wifi?  Of course, but for Apple, not for little old me and you.  (well, not for me anyway).

Comment: @danh Apparently, not for you :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is it possible using Objective-C on an iPhone to disable all WIFI connections?

Rant note: everybody sees OP is asking if it's possible or not? He doesn't mention the API has to be public. So here it is:

```
Class _SBWifiManager = objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager"); // Steal a class from SpringBoard
[[_SBWifiManager sharedInstance] setWiFiEnabled:NO]; // disable
```

([reference](https://github.com/DjKira/iOS-6-Headers/blob/master/SpringBoard/SBWiFiManager.h))

However, it has to be noted well that **mocking with the internals of iOS like this will for sure lead to the rejection of your app.** However, if you don't care about getting into the AppStore, and you're developing a jailbroken or in-house or personal app, this should be just fine.

Also, I think you should consider redesigning your app/code/logic if you need such a functionality. This shall not be necessary, normally.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot turn off WiFi from inside an app on a non-jailbroken device.

That said, you can detect if the device is connected over WiFi or a cell connection using the [Reachability Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html), and customize behavior based on that.