# Disable data connection of iOS device through app

Tags: ios

How to disconnect data connection of iOS device using objective C. If someone know about any private api for this then please tell me.

Comment: I believe that If such thing is possible, I't wouldn't be recommended by Apple and would probably be rejected, found this similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653058/disable-wifi-on-iphone-using-objective-c .

Comment: i know that that apple would not approve such types of apps but no care about it if you know about any such api then  tell me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any public API exist to do such a thing. But you can try to override the current settings for cellular and wifi settings using a configuration profile. For example when you click on a button download and install the profile.

Have a look at the 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iphoneconfigurationprofileref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13

and the Cellular Payloads, Wifi Payloads, VPN Payloads and allowAppCellularDataModification keys.