# Disable WIFI on iOS with Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to disable the Wifi for testing purpose on a test project. I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653058/disable-wifi-on-iphone-using-objective-c) how to disable it in Objective-C, but I don't know how to translate it in C#.

I tried creating a Binding project to bind the SBWiFiManager class, but SharedInstance always return an empty pointer.

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject)), Protocol]
interface SBWiFiManager {
    [Static, Export ("sharedInstance")]
    IntPtr SharedInstance { get; }
    [Export("setWiFiEnabled:")]
    void setWiFiEnabled (bool arg);

}
```

How can I disable the WIFI on iOS with C#?

Comment: Does the Objective-C code work if you use it in an Xcode project? Also remove the [Protocol] attribute, you're not binding a protocol.

Comment: Hum no, I can't seem to make it work

Comment: It's private API, so Apple might have removed it.

Comment: @AlexandrePepin were you ever able to achieve this?