# turn off wifi from device while xcode ui test execution is going on

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am facing a problem in xcode ui test.

That is, while my execution is going on, than in certain condition

```
i have to off my wifi
```

I know that i can use the command to do it

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

I have written a function in osx:

```
func runTerminalCommand(args: String...) -> Int32 {
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments = args
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
return task.terminationStatus
```

}

If i use this in osx, i can turn off wifi.

But i can not use this in my ios app or can not use this in my 
xcode ui test.

How i can off my wifi while xcode ui testing is ongoing ?

Comment: Can you add a button to your app that calls this code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653058/disable-wifi-on-iphone-using-objective-c

Answer (score 8):

With **Xcode 9** you can now just tap on the wifi button in the Control Center while running an UITest.

Here is a little helper function that opens the Control Center, taps on the wifi button and closes it again:

```
func toggleWiFi() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

    // open control center
    let coord1 = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.99))
    let coord2 = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.1))
    coord1.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: coord2)

    let wifiButton = springboard.switches["wifi-button"]
    wifiButton.tap()

    // open your app back again
    springboard.otherElements["com.your.app.identifier"].tap()
}
```

Just remember that you have to connect your device with a cable when running the test ;-)

Comment: Be aware that this is only working on real testing devices, not in simulators, where the Wifi-Button is not available