# is it possible to turn off wifi or switch iPhone to offline mode in codes in swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, swift4, offline-mode

I want to know is there any way to turn on or off the iPhone wifi or switch the device to offline mode in codes in swift 4 or not 
I know that apple may not allow the app can do such things to be distributed in App Store But it's Not important I just want to know is there any codes to do that or not (Just in swift 4)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653058/disable-wifi-on-iphone-using-objective-c

Comment: thanks But can you show me the swift codes please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 5 Solutions Collect From Internet About “How to turn off internet connection, bluetooth and WIFI programmatically?”

**Ans**

- You can’t. Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to change global system settings like that.
- There is no API available to control cellular data,wi-fi,bluetooth within in an app , User have to go to settings to enable or disable cellular data,wi-fi and bluetooth.
- This is not possible in iOS unless you jailbroke your device. Apple is not allowing any apps developer to access wifi/bluetooth. You can only check wifi/tooth is connected or not.
- You can’t do that using the iOS application. Apple not allowing it.
- Legally there is no way to do it. Even somehow if you are manage to do it, Apple will reject your app while submitting to AppStore.

**update**

I am not sure the following code will work or not, try once, initially add the [header file](https://github.com/pigigaldi/iOS-6-Headers/blob/master/SpringBoard/SBWiFiManager.h) to your project folder and create the bridging header to your code ,then use the below code where you need , for ref purpose I taken the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653058/disable-wifi-on-iphone-using-objective-c)

```
var tempSBWifiManager: SBWiFiManager = objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager")
 // Steal a class from SpringBoard
 tempSBWifiManager.sharedInstance().isWiFiEnabled = false
```

Comment: ok I know that the apple will reject the app I just want to know is there any codes or not ?

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi - not sure the reference link will work or not, if it is works, then use the update answer

Comment: I received this error in the first line of your codes 
(Use of undeclared type 'SBWiFiManager')

Comment: are you integrated the SBWiFiManager.h in your project from https://github.com/pigigaldi/iOS-6-Headers/blob/master/SpringBoard/SBWiFiManager.h

Comment: so I have to make a class and then put that code there and then using your codes here in my codes right ?

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi - the class is already available in that link , just drag and drop in the https://github.com/pigigaldi/iOS-6-Headers/blob/master/SpringBoard/SBWiFiManager.h in your project and it will create the bridging header, then use the above code it will work

Comment: ok thanks I will do it and if there was a problem I will comment here

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi - sure

Comment: Hello @Anbu.Karthik does Mobile Device Management accommodate the OPs point? 
I am looking for something similar in iOS but it seems there are a lot of restrictions with controlling wifi and mobile data.
Thanks